# Unusable dropdown menus in jmeter 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: java, 19.04, gui, jdk

Just installed jmeter 5.2.1 on Ubuntu desktop 19.04 and dropdown menus are showing only when I hold mouse button over them. When I release it it closes. So I am unable to access any menu option with mouse. It happens with both main menu (File, Edit etc..) and in dropdowns in interface (for instance when I try to choose HTTP request method).

I tried latest Oracle JDK 13 and 11 at the time of writing with the same result.

I also have another java app Soap UI installed where dropdowns work correctly.

I've found somewhere that the problem may be connected to bundled jre (for another java app), but as far as I know there is no bundled jre.

Comment: Just wondering: do you have exception messages on the console and/or in `bin/jmeter.log`?

Comment: I wasn't able to find logs neither in bin/jmeter in installation directory nor in /usr/local/bin/ where I created symlink nor in /var/logs. I was able to see some logs using yellow triangle in the upper right corner of the window. Didn't see anythin suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution" was to move application window. And then all dropdown menus started working just fine.

Not sure what is the reason, but I guess it is not related to java.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your problems, but failed at it. JMeter works for me on a freshly installed Ubuntu 19.04 Desktop with either OpenJDK 13 (installed from the Ubuntu repo) as well as Oracle JDK 13 (downloaded from Oracle).

My steps where:

- Install Ubuntu 19.04 on a fresh VM
- Open a terminal and install OpenJDK 13 and JMeter by typing the following commands

```
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jdk
cd $HOME
wget https://www-us.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz
tar xf apache-jmeter-5.2.1
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk-amd64
./bin/jmeter
```

The menus are all working as expected.

After that I downloaded the Oracle JDK 13 and extracted it in my home directory. I re-assigned the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to point to the newly extracted directory and ran JMeter again.

```
cd $HOME
tar xf jdk-13.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
export JAVA_HOME=jdk-13.0.1
cd apache-jmeter-5.2.1
./bin/jmeter
```

Again, I had no problem using the menus.

It might help, if you explain more exactly, how you installed your JDK and how you installed and started Apache JMeter.

Comment: I closely followed instructions for Java 11: https://web.archive.org/web/20191006155914/https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/06/new-oracle-java-11-installer-for-ubuntu.html and Java 13: https://web.archive.org/web/20191203054234/https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/09/install-oracle-java-13-on-ubuntu-linux.html